# Error while trying to use dynamic require links in php

Tags: php, dynamic, hyperlink, require

I am trying to use the code `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/mysql.php';` to include the file `/resources/mysql.php` (relative to root).

On my computer this works, and there are no problems, however my website users have complained that EVERY page except the root (/index.php) fails to load with the error

`Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/website/public_html/resources/mysql.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/website/public_html/website/events/index.php on line 2`

Why is this failing only on some computers. I have tried to replicate the problem on my computer and even after clearing my browser and DNS cache I cannot get this error to occur. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to dynamically include php files?

Comment: Why can't you just define your url as something like this: define('BASE_URL', 'http://yoursite.com/'); in your config file and then use BASE_URL.'/resources/mysql.php/'  ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks weird that you can access the website but some people not.

You could use ( if you are in php > 5.3 ):

```
__DIR__
```

You could also use:

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

Be aware that DOCUMENT_ROOT is not available ( i think ) when you are running your script through CLI

Comment: Apparently I can't post my own answer for another 8 hrs so I'll post it here:

Comment: My website is set up as an addon-domain of another website. The people getting the error were using the original website directory instead of the addon-domain. What PHP perceives as the root changes whether you are on the addon-domain or the original website directory thus invalidating all file links